# Laravel php version changed also changed in htaccess

Tags: php, laravel

Recently i have add a line 
`AddHandler application/x-httpd-php71 .php71 .php`
to .htaccess 
 to change php version:
7.1.13

i got this error:
`PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface::setLocale($locale) must be compatible with Symfony\Contracts\Translation\LocaleAwareInterface::setLocale(string $locale) in /home/sistemc/public_html/saudagarCetak/vendor/symfony/translation/TranslatorInterface.php on line 24`

i have added this line in my composer : `symfony/translation-contracts": "^1.1.6"`

As I can't get ssh/Terminal from my hosting service cause they don't have it...
Normally i just need to upgrade the composer already I have added this line in my composer.json

composer:

````
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",

    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "intervention/image": "^2.5",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
 "symfony/translation-contracts": "^1.1.6"   
}```
````

Comment: did you try composer update?

Comment: I can't do it on live server cause I don't have ssh in my hosting

Comment: you can update in your local and upload vendor folder to live server

Comment: ```symfony/translation-contracts": "^1.1.6```  i want to add this line in composer.json and update but,after adding this line i cant update my composer

Comment: can you post your composer.json file

Comment: Please check above i have added

Answer (score 0):

You said you don't have ssh key for your hosting, you can get terminal option to enable by contacting hosting providers they will activate it for you.

And second, you can update the composer file locally and then upload the Laravel vendor folder to hosting but I am not sure about this command but for other packages this technique 100% works.

```
symfony/translation-contracts": "^1.1.6
```

Comment: Hosting service said they can't provide ssh/terminal services

Comment: Then check manually that i explained. Update composer on local with these packgae and upload vendor folder on hosting

Comment: terminal and ssh are the same ?

Comment: They are same but methods are seprate. Terminal mean you are in your serve as cli using gui while ssh mean you enter in to your server using a secure key. You can also use putty for this process. For putty you have to open firewall port.

Comment: What hosting service are you using? And do you have cpanel or something else

Comment: Yes,using cpanel can you guide me for putty or provide me some documents

Comment: For putty, ssh enabled is also required. And why hosting provider support are not enabling for you, this is not possible that they can't.

Comment: Finally the hosting guys solved it for me...without ssh